# Uniqueness of Spectral Decomposition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, mathematics, density-operator, eigenvalue

In one of the papers (related to Quantum Computing) I am reading, I came across this statement which says,

> An elementary result is that sets of orthogonal rank-one eigenprojectors of Hermitian operators
> are not unique when the spectrum includes degenerate eigenvalues, and that uniqueness is recovered when
> rank-one eigenprojectors are combined into full-rank eigenprojectors, corresponding to maximal subsets of
> rank-one eigenprojectors for distinct eigenvalues.

> For any finite-dimensional Hermitian operator $\rho$, there is a "unique" set of full-rank projectors $\Pi_k$ such that, $\rho = \sum_k Tr(\rho\Pi_k)\Pi_k$, which also satisfy $\sum_k\Pi_k = I $  and $\Pi_k\rho = \rho\Pi_k = Tr(\rho\Pi_k)\Pi_k$

Here I understand that Spectral decomposition may not be unique if there is degeneracy involved.
What exactly are the "full rank projectors" mentioned here, and why do they make the decomposition unique.

Comment: which paper would this be?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero This is a paper on Efficient Classical Simulation of Concordant Computation by Hugo Cable and Daniel E Browne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following matrix:

$$A=\pmatrix{1 &0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2}$$

I can decompose $A$ as the sum of projectors onto 1D subspaces as follows:

$$A = 1 \cdot\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} + 2\cdot\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}+2\cdot\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1}$$

But this decomposition is not unique, because I could also use this one:

$$A = 1 \cdot\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} + 2\cdot\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}}+2\cdot\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\\0&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}}$$

Each projection matrix written above is a projection onto a 1D subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.  However, since the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$ is 2D, the second and third projections are not unique.

What I *can* do, however, is express $A$ as

$$A = 1 \cdot\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} + 2\cdot\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}$$

Now the first projection is onto a 1D subspace, but the second projection is onto the full 2D subspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$.  This is what your paper meant - the projections should be onto the full eigenspaces, not just 1D subspaces, if you want the decomposition to be unique.

Comment: I agree. Actually the **spectral decomposition** is the map associating eigenvalues to the  orthogonal projectors onto the corresponding eigenspaces. This map is **always** unique.